# How to disable location service programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I have the following:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    ...
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
            locationManager.distanceFilter = 3000.0
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("my location: \(locations.first?.coordinate)")
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.delegate = nil
    }
}
```

But even when the app is turned off i see the location service icon in status bar:

[image]

I wonder if there is a way to disable it programmatically. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` if you need it only when the app is open. You need to modify info.plist file accordingly as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your plist file, you must make sure the location row  is  `Privacy - LocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` not  `Privacy - LocationAlwaysUsageDescription`